# perl DBI and prepared statement name conflicts

Tags: perl, postgresql, concurrency, dbi

I'm using Perl's DBI for postgreSQL access, and I noticed that when I have multiple concurrent processes preparing the same query, they seem to end up with the same prepared statement name on the server, creating a conflict.

```
2014-02-10 10:04:11.802650500 DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  prepared statement    "dbdpg_p20307_185" already exists at /usr/sbin/mslrest.pl line 207.
2014-02-10 10:04:11.804659500 [Mon Feb 10 10:04:11 2014] [error] DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  prepared statement "dbdpg_p20307_185" already exists at /usr/sbin/mslrest.pl line 207.
```

Is there a way to pass in the name of the prepared statement so that I can randomize it and avoid this conflict?

Comment: I wonder if this could be caused by using a copy of the same dbh (due to forking) in two processes. Are you?

Comment: Not sure, I'm using Mojolicious::Lite and Hypnotoad. It likely does fork. I could try re-connecting to ensure that the dbh isn't shared...

Comment: Yes, I think that was it. As a quick test I reconnected with every request, and the problem does not appear. Now I can put in a proper solution. Thank you!

Comment: are you using prepare() or prepare_cached()?

Answer (score 3):

The forking of the process resulted in each worker having the same dbh. Ensuring that each is unique fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Never pass DB handles into subprocesses.  Create the handle in the subprocess and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

For my Mojolicious application I use a shared instance of
[DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aConnector).

Whenever I need a database connection I ask the connector instance for one. Disconnects and forks are handled automatically.